# How to fetch location coordinates in flight mode or sim card absent state?

Tags: android, gps, location

I am working on an android application in that application i need to fetch location coordinates even when device is in flight mode or even sim card absent state. I had tried with the below code but i am getting latitude and longitude as 0.0 generally if network is there its working fine. Please help me to solve this.

```
public class GpsTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GpsTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context; //getting context
        getLocation();  //method calling
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        //checkPermissions();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                try {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    }
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    //  Toast.makeText(mContext, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                if (location != null) {
                    latitude = location.getLatitude(); //getting latitude
                    longitude = location.getLongitude(); //getting longitude
                }
            }
        }
        // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            try {

                if (location == null) { //checking location whether null or not 

                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {  //if not equals null
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude(); //getting latitude from GPS
                            longitude = location.getLongitude(); //getting longitude from GPS

                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                //  Toast.makeText(mContext, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Airplane mode is On.Please disable ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //airplanemodealert();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 */
public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        try {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GpsTracker.this);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // Toast.makeText(mContext, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 */
public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude(); //getting latitude
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 */
public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();    //getting longitude
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

private static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {

    return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;

}

private void showAlert() {
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setMessage("Airplane mode is On.Please disable ");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 */
public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}


public void airplanemodealert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setMessage("Airplane mode is On.Please disable ");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Is this even possible?

Comment: @Pawamoy I think it is, because to compute a GPS position, your receiver only needs to get a signal from satellites from which it will compute pseudo-ranges etc. So I'm not really sure it will be problematic. Also, take a look at this: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8188/airplane-mode-does-not-disable-gps-is-it-safe-to-use-gps-in-flight. But if you meant it is not possible because of API-related reasons, then well, okay.

Comment: Well I would suggest that you **make sure** it is possible with Android-based devices (and which ones and which versions), and then try your code again. If it returns `0.0` I would suggest the API accepts the request but cannot return any useful information.